# Listbox filled with UserControls. Access to Controls in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

first of all. This community is awesome. Helped me a lot.
I try to explain my Problem. I am a total beginner. I ve found a way how i can insert a UserControl into a ListBox in the MainWindow. This works quite well like this

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
        Project project = new Project();
        ProjectPanel.Items.Add(project);
```

The problem is, that after those UserControl(Project) which i designed with Labels and Textblocks, is shown in the listBox(ProjectPanel) i want to get the Controls in that UserControl. But i dont know how to do that.

Best thing would be, if i select the UserControl in the Listbox to get all Infos in that selectet userControl.

Thank you
BR
Nasuf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# usercontrol how to access all child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346533/c-sharp-usercontrol-how-to-access-all-child-controls)

Comment: `var selectedProject = (Project)ProjectPanel.SelectedItem;`

Comment: Despite duplicate is for winforms the same principle applies: add dedicated property (dependency property if you intent to use bindings).